# Download RTSP stream to file

Tags: python

I recently purchased a couple WANSCAM Wireless cameras that allow you to stream the video over RTSP.  I was hoping to find an easy way to do this with python.  End game is to buffer like 5 secs of the feed to a file then stream that file to a webpage via flask or some other light weight python framework for viewing while on my home network.

Any ideas?

Comment: though old post, I think this is what you are looking for: http://www.onegoodidea.com/source.html